# A function that creates functions named after arguments passed in

Tags: python, xml, automated-tests

Is there a way to make a function that makes other functions to be called later named after the variables passed in?

For the example let's pretend https://example.com/engine_list returns this xml file, when I call it in get_search_engine_xml

```
<engines>
    <engine address="https://www.google.com/">Google</engine>
    <engine address="https://www.bing.com/">Bing</engine>
    <engine address="https://duckduckgo.com/">DuckDuckGo</engine>
</engines>
```

And here's my code:

```
import re
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
base_url = 'https://example.com'

def make_safe(s):
    s = re.sub(r"[^\w\s]", '', s)
    s = re.sub(r"\s+", '_', s)
    s = str(s)
    return s

# This is what I'm trying to figure out how to do correctly, create a function
# named after the engine returned in get_search_engine_xml(), to be called later
def create_get_engine_function(function_name, address):
    def function_name():
        r = requests.get(address)
    return function_name

def get_search_engine_xml():
    url = base_url + '/engine_list'
    r = requests.get(url)
    engines_list = str(r.content)
    engines_root = ET.fromstring(engines_list)
    for child in engines_root:
        engine_name = child.text.lower()
        engine_name = make_safe(engine_name)
        engine_address = child.attrib['address']
        create_get_engine_function(engine_name, engine_address)

## Runs without error.
get_search_engine_xml()

## But if I try to call one of the functions.
google()
```

I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'google' is not defined
```

Defining engine_name and engine_address seems to be working when I log it out. So I'm pretty sure the problem lies in create_get_engine_function, which admittedly I don't know what I'm doing and I was trying to piece together from similar questions.

Can you name a function created by another function with an argument that's passed in? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: There are definitely better ways, what is your end goal?

Comment: Basically the app takes user input, and does stuff. The input goes into a switch function to figure out what to do, including call any of these functions by name, along with some other static functions and maybe some more dynamically made ones. Later I may need to call get_search_engine_xml() again and if the xml changed remove functions that no longer exist or add new ones based on the xml that's returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign them to [globals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals)

```
def create_get_engine_function(function_name, address):
    def function():
        r = requests.get(address)

    function.__name__ = function_name
    function.__qualname__ = function_name  # for Python 3.3+ 
    globals()[function_name] = function
```

Although, depending on what you're actually trying to accomplish, a better design would be to store all the engine names/addresses in a dictionary and access them as needed:

```
# You should probably should rename this to 'parse_engines_from_xml'
def get_search_engine_xml(): 
    ...
    search_engines = {} # maps names to addresses
    for child in engines_root:
        ...
        search_engines[engine_name] = engine_address
    return search_engines

engines = get_search_engine_xml()

e = requests.get(engines['google'])
<do whatever>
e = requests.get(engines['bing'])
<do whatever>
```

Comment: I would probably just return the search engines from the `get_search_engine_xml()` vs. the global.

Comment: @AChampion I agree, that would be better.  I've incorporated your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the super quick replay @friendlydog, and the improvement AChampion. Let me bang on my code for a bit, as it's working if I load a local xml file with example code, but didn't immediately fix what I'm working on. Probably my bad there but want to get it working just in case I'm wrong. But definitely answered the core of the question, How to name a function, created by a function based on an argument.

Comment: I also had an issue with engine_names looking like strings but not actually being strings. Just in case it has to do with requests I've updated my example to include it.